# Search Query based on associatin Rails4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails4. I want to search all the products which are of metal_type:Gold.metal_type is in metal_spec table.
Product belongs_to metal_spec, metal_type is boolean, if its 1 then its Gold.

Product.rb

```
def self.search(query)
 self.joins(:metal_spec).to_a.where(metal_type: "#{query}")
end
```

In product Controller

```
@products = Product.search(params[:search]).to_a
```

In template

```
<%= form_tag(sub_category_products_path(params[:sub_category_id]), :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
  <%= select_tag "search", "<option>0</option><option>1</option>".html_safe%>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

Its not working, Please help. 
Thanks In advance

Comment: Remove the `to_a` in the `self.search` method. Make it `self.joins(:metal_spec).where(metal_type: "#{query}")`

Comment: Also, you will have to link the metal_spec table and products table in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code shoud do it:

```
# product.rb
def self.search(query)
  self.joins(:metal_spec).where(metal_spec: { metal_type: query })
end
```

Also, a little improvement for your `select_tag`:

```
select_tag "search", options_for_select([0, 1])
```

---

If you want to use `radio_button_tag` instead of the `select_tag`:

```
radio_button_tag 'search', 0, params[:search] == '0'
radio_button_tag 'search', 1, params[:search] == '1'
```

Documentation about `rabio_button_tag` here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/radio_button_tag

> radio_button_tag(name, value, checked = false, options = {})

Comment: Hi, I need one more help. Instead of select_tag , I am using radio_button_tag. How can I show the selected tag when Gold is selected , after submitting the form?

Comment: I updated my answer with the relevant code @dips (I think that the `select_tag( 'search', options_for_select([['Not Gold', 0],['Gold', 1]], params[:search]) )` is a better solution IMO)